# How can disable automatically restart in startup and recovery by cmd?

Tags: cmd, windows-8.1

how can disable automatically restart in startup and recovery by cmd?
on windows 8.1 I try to invoke this command:

bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures

or\and

bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No

but it isn't changed

Comment: why this question be closed? I need you help! I need answer urgent for this q